# How can I replace the "url" field by a hyperlink in a bibtex bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

[image: I would like to have a hyperlink in a bibtex generated reference.]

I have tried:

```
@article{Berg_2011,
  author  = {Berg, Anne T. and Scheffer, Ingrid E.},
  title   = {New concepts in classification of the epilepsies: Entering the 21st century},
  journal = {Epilepsia},
  volume  = {52},
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {1058-1062},
  keywords= {Classification, Etiology, Seizure semiology},
  url     = {\href{https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1528-1167.2011.03101.x}{Pubmed}},
  year    = {2011}
}
```

Comment: I got it using "note" field. Is there another alternative??

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Indicating the full DOI might still be useful to the reader using a paper copy?

Comment: Are you using `hyperref` and `url` packages?

Comment: thank you! I have already got how I do this...